# Why won't my Boids follow the Target?

Tags: particles, boids

Got some boids, have them following a target in the rules. However, they are going in the opposite direction and I have no idea why.

[PROJECT FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5sqfpsj1mqvun0o/Boids%20Why.blend?dl=0)

This is the first frame (boids circled, arrow pointing to target):

[image]

This is further in the animation. Notice the target is going one way and the birds another:

[image]

Would love some insight, thanks.

Comment: maybe put the Goal first, before Flock? Also you'll probably have to change the Movement values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As moonboots mentioned, the first goal of the boids will be prioritized. So you should set the goal to the first place. I lowered the air speed and unchecked whole collection and checked "pick random":

[image]

Comment: Thank you @chris, this has helped a lot. I thought I tried everything but after I changed 'whole collection' to 'pick random' the whole thing came to life. Cheers!

Comment: Glad I could help